# on Submit in jquery triggers Uncaught RangeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to post a form using AJAX, to accomplish this, I'm using jQuery. The code I wrote for this is the following:

```
$("#addStaffForm").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formPost = $.post("/medewerkers-toevoegen", {
        "_token": $("input[name=_token]"),
        "voorletters": $("input[name=voorletters]"),
        "tussenvoegsels": $("input[name=tussenvoegsels]"),
        "achternaam": $("input[name=achternaam]"),
        "gebruikersnaam": $("input[name=gebruikersnaam]"),
        "wachtwoord": $("input[name=wachtwoord]")
    });

    formPost.done(function(data) {
        console.log("data");
    });
});
```

Simple enough, however, when I try to actually submit the form I get this:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.type (jquery.min.js:1)
```

I have no idea why this error could be given to me, and the only explanation I could think of is me creating an infinite loop, but I can't seem to find one.

How could it be that this small, simple piece of code won't work like i want it to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! I forgot that I'm actually sending entire jquery elements instead of input values.

```
$("#addStaffForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var token = $("input[name=_token]").val();
        var voorletters = $("input[name=voorletters]").val();
        var tussenvoegsels = $("input[name=tussenvoegsels]").val();
        var achternaam = $("input[name=achternaam]").val();
        var gebruikersnaam = $("input[name=gebruikersnaam]").val();
        var wachtwoord = $("input[name=token]").val();


        $.post("/medewerkers-toevoegen", {
            "_token": token,
            "voorletters": voorletters,
            "tussenvoegsels": tussenvoegsels,
            "achternaam": achternaam,
            "gebruikersnaam": gebruikersnaam,
            "wachtwoord": wachtwoord
        }, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

works for me!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
  var params = {
        "_token": $("input[name=_token]").val(),
        "voorletters": $("input[name=voorletters]").val(),
        "tussenvoegsels": $("input[name=tussenvoegsels]").val(),
        "achternaam": $("input[name=achternaam]").val(),
        "gebruikersnaam": $("input[name=gebruikersnaam]").val(),
        "wachtwoord": $("input[name=wachtwoord]").val()
  }
  var formPost = $.post("/medewerkers-toevoegen", params);
```